# How to return function results in an array?

Tags: python-2.7

I have one function where I am calculating the CPU usage of a test case. The function works, but I would like to append the result of the subtraction in a list for the further usage.
For example, first I subtract `10` and `15`, which is `-5`. At this point the list looks like `[-5]`. Next I subtract `20` and `30`, which is `-10`. Now I want the list to look like `[-5, -10]`. My current code is (python 2.7):

```
import  psutil

class  CPU():
    def __init__(self):
        self.cpu_start()

    def cpu_start(self):
        global a
        a= psutil.cpu_percent(interval=1, percpu=False)
        print a

    def cpu_end(self):
        global b
        b = psutil.cpu_percent(interval=1, percpu=False)
        print b

    def diff(self):
        c= a-b
        list = []
        list.append(c)
        print list

def main():
    CPU()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Please include the `subtract` function in your post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make the `diff` function return `a-b`, and append that to an array:

```
import psutil
class CPU:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cpu_start()
        self.list = []
        self.a = 0
        self.b = 0
        self.c = 0
    def cpu_start(self):
        self.a = psutil.cpu_percent(interval=1, percpu=False)
        return self.a
    def cpu_end(self):
        self.b = psutil.cpu_percent(interval=1, percpu=False)
        return self.b
    def diff(self):
        self.c = self.cpu_start() - self.cpu_start()
        return self.c

def main():
    cpu = CPU()
    results = []
    while True:
        results.append(cpu.diff())
        print results

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Remember that when you're using a class function, you need to create an object of that class, such as `cpu = CPU()` - I'm creating an object called `cpu` of class `CPU`, initialised with nothing. Then the `__init__` function will create `a` and `b`(created as `self.a` and `self.b`, because they're local) and store them locally in that class. The `diff()` function, takes no arguments, but returns the difference of `a` and `b` which are stored locally in that class. Then I create a list called `results` with no elements. I run `cpu.diff()`, which gets the difference from `cpu_start()` and `cpu_end()`, and append the result to the `results` array. This is run in a loop, constantly appending to the array and printing it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @bharath what exactly do you mean by "taking inputs randomly"... the code you posted just subtracted hardcoded numbers, what I provided does exactly the same and stores them to a list, like you asked.

Comment: @bharath those aren't random inputs, they're averages of the system CPU usage.

Comment: yes, can you help me like how to pass those outputs in to a list.

Comment: @bharath if this solved the issue please mark the answer as solved